# How To Force Java Compiler to ONLY compile the source file I specify?

Tags: java, javac

The java 12.0.1 compiler (my tests here are all run in MS Windows) has some really odd behavior when using the -sourcepath argument, with regards to what it decides to compile.  The easiest way to explain this is to provide two examples and cite the differences in behavior.

***Example 1:***

Source file "A.java"

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        B.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Source file "B.java"

```
public class B {
    public static void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

To compile example 1, we just use the following:

```
javac -sourcepath . A.java
```

This will compile both A.java and B.java and create A.class and B.class.  We expect it to also compile B.java because A depends on it.  Now wait a second or so and without modifying either ".java" source file, simply re-run the compilation command above.  You will find that it re-compiles A.java and a new A.class is created (with updated timestamp), but B.class is not re-compiled.  Ok, this is pretty much what one might expect.  Now let's compare this to the next example below.

***Example 2:***

Source file "example2/A.java"

```
package example2;
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        B.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Source file "example2/B.java"

```
package example2;
public class B {
    public static void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

The source files are the same, except everything is moved into a package.  We want to compile the two source files while currently in the "example2" folder.  So we use the following command:

```
javac -sourcepath .. A.java
```

This will again compile both A.java and B.java and create A.class and B.class.  No problems here, same as before.  Note that -sourcepath is now ".." because that is the "root" source folder now that everything is in a package.  Now wait a second or so and without modifying either source file, simply re-run the compilation command above.  You will find that it re-compiles BOTH A.java and B.java and a new A.class and B.class file are created (with updated timestamps).

Note the difference in compilation behavior when the javac command is run the second time.  When -sourcefile was "." and the files were not in a package, the second "javac" command only compiles the source file specified on the command line.  But when -sourcefile is ".." and the classes are in a package, the second "javac" command ALWAYS compiles all the dependent source files, regardless if the unspecified source files need to be recompiled or not.

The question is why?  What arguments can I pass to the javac command-line to stop example 2 from unconditionally recompiling all the dependent source files, if their class files have a newer timestamp than the source files?

Comment: Here's a third experiment, try compiling just B in example 2 :)

Comment: @yhyrcanus Then it only recompiles B, as expected.  Attempts to recompile A only, result in B also being recompiled because there is a dependency that javac detects.  Problem is, B doesn't need to be recompiled because it's already up to date.  This isn't a big deal with 2 source files, but when there's dozens of source files, it matters.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should be *in* `..`, that is to say in the directory that contains the head of the package structure, and the command should be `javac example2/A.java` etc.

Comment: @user207421 Then what's the purpose of the -sourcepath option?  If you "must" be in the root source folder when compiling, why even have a command-line option that allows you to be in a different folder?  Clearly that's the whole point of -sourcepath, i.e. to allow you to compile from whatever folder you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurs because javac compares timestamps between the .java file and the .class file. It uses `-sourcepath` to find the source files, and `-classpath` to find the class files. Therefore, your issue can be fixed by specifying the classpath:

```
javac -sourcepath .. -classpath .. A.java
```

Comment: This seems to be the best explanation, and the fix works.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I've removed my suggestion that this is a bug, since I've accepted another answer as the best explanation.

As an aside, there seems to be no sensible way to report this as a bug to the OpenJDK.  I googled and searched around the OpenJDK website and it seems that the bugs.openjdk.java.net is only for trusted developers.  I guess I could throw it up on the OpenJDK mailing list, but that seems like a hack.  So I am not even sure where to report this bug, sadly.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug but if you want to report one: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2015-December/003840.html

Comment: It's the same behaviour in javac version 1.8.0_212.

Comment: @assylias Well that thread is an interesting discussion between a bunch of people arguing about where to report OpenJDK bugs, but it doesn't actually suggest a usable answer, other than to suggest reporting it to Oracle at bugreport.java.com which is probably creating a non-public report that only Oracle will look at.  Doesn't OpenJDK want its community to be able to report bugs somewhere other than Oracle's private bug database?

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to `..`. If you go to the source root, the default package:

```
cd ..
javac -sourcepath . ex/A.java
```

everything works (at my place): no recompile of B.java.

It might be due to the `-classpath` too, but I would rather think of some esoteric problem with package paths.

Comment: Yes this is a workaround, but it also defeats the whole purpose of the -sourcepath command-line option, which enables you to be in whatever current directory you want, when compiling source files.